# Modifying the variables in .tpl files in drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I know that this is bit of a conceptual question but after searching alot i am unable to grab the concept that is why i am hoping to get help from this platform.

I often need to change some markup or styles etc on the elements let se in `$page['highlight']`

When i `var_dump` any variable in any .tpl file it gives just a basic information. Let say i have to add additional `div` element in a content that is set to be rendered in $page['highlight'] region. What would be the way that i grab that element and alter it before it rendered on page.

The same case happend to me when i made a page view in drupal. I had a custom .tpl file which was displaying the view and all records were getting displayed by a single variable like

```
print $rows
```

I am not specifically asking for the code but it would be helpful to many other users including me to grab the concept with a little example.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to do the same things you say.

In views, you can customize your results by **Theme: information** option. Is's in the bottom-right part of the view configuration. Here you have the option to create a new file and customize the view results. In your case you need to create a new **Row style output:** (it contains the value of *$row* variable).

[image: I attach a file with the example]

Here is a tutorial: https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/views-templates/

About the *$page* variable. You have different options depends on the context. For example if you need to add a  in all pages, the best option is to edit the *page.tpl.php* in your theme.

Another option is to change the *template.php* of your theme, but only if you need to add html in some cases.

Hope it helps.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks you have told me the option to edit views. But regarding page, If i open page.tpl, I see variable $page['content']. Lets say i have a third party slider plugin that i embeded it in content region. Now i don't have control on the html of that plugin and i want to grab all the markup generated by that plugin and edit it on runtime. How to do it ?

Comment: The slider is a drupal module? Because I am sure that is a tpl file in the module folder. Try to copy it in your theme folder, and drupal gets it instead of the original.  Tell me if it doesn't work

Comment: No i just gave u an example ... in its simple form if $page['content'] generating the html for me ...how can i add my html tags and stuff within the $page['content'] ?

Comment: As I said, you have to add tpl files into your theme folder. This tpl files are placed into $page['content'] in the most cases.